# Is it possible in Silverlight to bind the column header text of a DataGrid to a resource string?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I need to bind the column Header text of a DataGrid to a Resource string in a XAML file. Does anybody know if this is possible ?

The column Header definition looks like this but I would like to replace the "MyHeaderText" with text from a resource file:-

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="MyHeaderText" Binding="{Binding SomeData}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

The Resource string would be set up in the UserControl.Resources section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header presentation area is limited. You can achieve this though by utilizing a string instead of a UIElement. Make sure you have the xmlns for the "System" namespace in your xaml file like so:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then have the following defined in your UserControl's Resources section:

```
<sys:String x:Key="MyHeader">My Header Text</sys:String>
```

Then you can do basically what Sorskoot said and you shouldn't receive an error:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource MyHeader}" Binding="{Binding SomeData}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything like:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource SomeData}" 
                         IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Where "SomeData" is your resource.

Comment: I get the following error after trying this:

AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

Note, you can do more than just use a text value if you want, but you need to use the HeaderStyle property instead of the Header Property.